# jquery not just write a lot of click function

Tags: jquery

I have a question about jquery `onclick` function, the question is not bug;
when i write some button click functions that use jquery, i have write a lot of jquery, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dp1').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
    $('#dp2').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });

    $("#addNewQ").on('click', function(){
       .......
    });
    $('#addNew').on('click', function(){
       .......
    });
    $('#addText').on('click', function(){
       .......
    });

});
```

My question is how to write this better. I don't want to write a lot of click functions.

I have try to google, but I don't know the keyword. Thanks !

Comment: Are the all the click events the same?  You can do `$("#addNewQ,#addNew,#addText").on('click'`, or give those a class, and then do a `$('.add').on('click'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these click events are running the same function, then you could give a class to multiple elements, and use that. For example, your date pickers could have `class="datepicker"` added to them, which will just then require the 1 event listener:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
       format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

However if each of these click events will run a different function, then you are best to have a different click event listener for each.

However, this doesn't mean you must list your click event listeners in 1 long DOM ready function. You can use Javascript OOP to better organise your click events.

You may find this article referring to Javascript OOP has some use for you:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-basics-of-object-oriented-javascript/